# Function which produces new variable for use outside of function - PHP

Tags: php

How would I alter the function below to produce a new variable for use outside of the function?

**PHP Function**

```
    function sizeShown ($size)
    {
        // *** Continental Adult Sizes ***
        if (strpos($size, 'continental-')!== false)
        {
            $size = preg_replace("/\D+/", '', $size);
            $searchsize = 'quantity_c_size_' . $size;            
        }

      return $searchsize;
```

**Example**

```
<?php
    sizeShown($size);
    $searchsize;  
?>
```

This currently produces a `null` value and `Notice: undefined variable`.

So the function takes one argument, a variable containing a string relating to size. It checks the variable for the string 'continental-', if found it trims the string of everything except the numbers. A new variable `$searchsize` is created which appends 'quantity_c_size_' to the value stored in `$size`.

So the result would be like so ... `quantity_c_size_45`

I want to be able to call `$searchsize` outside of the function within the same script.

Can anybody provide a solution? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the global keyword, like so:

```
function test () {
    global $test_var;
    $test_var = 'Hello World!';
}

test();
echo $test_var;
```

However, this is usually not a good coding practice. So I would suggest the following:

```
function test () {
    return 'Hello World!';
}

$test_var = test();
echo $test_var;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the first example isn't good coding practice? Thanks

Comment: Think of it this way, lets say you decide to make a WordPress theme. Your modifying the home page, and decide to store a hard-coded array of featured posts. If you just so happen to use store them in the global variable `$posts` you will be overwriting a very important WordPress variable. And now every call that WordPress or its' plugins make to `$posts` will be messed up. As it turns out, WordPress has a dozen or so of these commonly named global variables.

Comment: The above is just 1 example for 1 reason why it is better not to rely on global variables for everything. In truth, there are several reasons that you learn as you become more familiar with PHP, but that is beyond the scope of this Stackoverflow Question. So I will simply say this, just trust me on this one for now, it will be better for you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - Can I just ask?  If I only use the one `global` variable in this instance i.e. `$searchsize` is that really a big issue?

Comment: @aphextwix Having limited number of `global` variables is generally ok. I am assuming you are relatively new or inexperienced with PHP, so it is good to learn to use `global`. However, a nice trick to use is making a [static variables class](http://3v4l.org/kSHpJ), and using that instead of `global`. But that is a little more advanced, and uses OOP which you may not be familiar with yet.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I'm relatively new to PHP (6 months experience) OOP is something I'm coming to terms with at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

In the function 'sizeShown' you are just returning the function. You forgot to echo the function when you call your function.

```
echo sizeShown($size);

echo $searchsize;  

?>
```

But the way you call $searchsize is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and I might not be understanding the OP's question properly, but why couldn't you just do this:

```
<?php
    $searchsize = sizeShown($size);  
?>
```

You're already returning `$searchsize` from the `sizeShown` method. So if you simply assign the result of the function to the `$sizeShown` variable, you should have what you want.