# Access Global Variables within a Static Method in PHP

Tags: php

I have some php code that works similar to this:

```
$var1 = 'Variable 1';
$var2 = 'Variable 2';

class myClass {

    function __construct() {
        $this->var1 = $GLOBALS['var1'];
        $this->var2 = $GLOBALS['var2'];
    }

    public function returnVars() {
        return $this->var1 . ' ' . $this->var2; //Works fine
    }

    public static function returnVars2() {
        //What should I do here?
    }

}
```

If I instantiate this class using `$myClass = new myClass()`, I can use the `returnVars()` method or just get `var1` and `var2` from the class just fine. My problem is I need to use the global variables `$var1` and `$var2` within the static method `returnVars2()`. I can't use this `$this` keyword because the class isn't instantiated (and they get declared inside the constructor), but I still can't access the global variables normally.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the `global` keyword?

Comment: See this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530954/function-which-produces-new-variable-for-use-outside-of-function-php/25531030)

Comment: Exactly like you do in the constructor? By the way, you should not use global variables, just send the parameters you need to the method. Or perhaps you mean to use contants instead of variables?

Comment: This code is very bad in terms of architecture

Comment: You access global variables in static methods exactly the same way you access them in any other function. Either by using `$GLOBALS` or by using the `global` declaration. What's the problem?

Comment: Since you appreciate suggestions, here's a one: Pass variables that class need as parameters, via `__construct()`. You'd learn why it's better when reach unit-testing and your code base will become large.

Comment: @jeroen My code is a little bit more complex than this, involving a lot of files and other methods, so globals are the easiest way to go. However, you are right that I should make them constants!

Answer (score 8):

Declare the variables as static members:

```
class foo {
    public static $var1;
    public static $var2;

    function __construct() {
       foo::$var1 = $GLOBALS['var1'];
       foo::$var2 = $GLOBALS['var2'];
    }
}
```

Then you can access them as `foo::$varX` in any method within that class, static or not.

Comment: `self::$var1` is better, because when he decide to change a class name, then he'd have to rewrite all those `foo::$var1` everywhere. Breaks DRY principle, therefore +0

Comment: This would depend on an object being instantiated at least once before you use the static method, otherwise the variables will not be initialized.

Comment: @jeroen: true enough, but there's no other way to do it. can't do it at the attribute definition,b ecause that'd be an expression and can't be resolved at compile time.

Comment: You could instantiate an object in the `returnVars2` function to ensure that the constructor has run.

Comment: @barmar: that might work. never tried instantiating an "self" object inside the object's own constructor. seems canibalistic, somehow.

Answer (score 3):

or much simple solutuion:

```
$mydataExample=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

function myDataFunction() {
  global $mydataExample;
  return $mydataExample;
}
```

and then we can use this array in **public static function**:

```
public static function example() {
 $data = myDataFunction();
 print_r($data);
}
```